# How to order by Special character in mysql

Tags: mysql

my column value is

```
firstname
===============
mufi**alam
lam**slam
zia**busa
```

i want to oreder by after star in value.
how we can usewhich  query of mySql

Comment: SELECT Firstname
FROM persons
WHERE Firstname LIKE '%**%' ESCAPE '$'

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(firstname, '*', -1) AS foo FROM Table1
   order by foo;
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd847b/1)

or this demo if you want show the firstname column

[**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd847b/2)

or this without foo column , just order by after *.

```
  SELECT firstname  FROM Table1
  order by SUBSTRING_INDEX(firstname, '*', -1);
```

[**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd847b/5)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT firstname FROM persons
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(firstname, '*', -1);
```

**Output**

```
|  FIRSTNAME |
--------------
| mufi**alam |
|  zia**busa |
|  lam**slam |
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5454c/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

SELECT first_name FROM persons ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(first_name, '*', -1) [desc,asc];

here desc means descending order,
     asc means ascending order.